Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 5 not booting installer
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in Thinkpad E14 and am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 LTS alongside Windows.
My USB drive has a Ubuntu image, but when I try to initialize with a USB drive it seems like it is not working and I can't install Ubuntu. I thought it was the drive, but I tried it on another computer, and the dual boot started. The option Allows Microsoft 3rd party UEFI CA is on. Can someone help me?

I'm struggling with the same issue. My HW is HP EliteBook 840 G11. I did come across a post on this site that may help you. It hasn't helped me but it seems that it works for some people. Good luck!
Thinkpad E14 Gen 4 not booting installer
